# Custom calculations in an interactive PDF scale/checklist?

Tags: javascript, pdf, interactive, acrobat

I am looking to achieve a few custom calculations within a interactive PDF scale/checklist.

I've attached an annotated image attached to better explain the type of calculations I'm looking to do, but here is a written summary too:

1.) Have a specific field sum the # of checkboxes that have been checked in the same column (ie: if 2 of 4 checkboxes have been checked, the sum field would populate with the number 2)

2.) Have a field show the results of the sum of a different field multiplied by a specific value (ie: Sum of "Field A" x 2 = "Field B")

Any help would be greatly apreciated!

Thank you

I'm completely unsure of where to even start!

Comment: I think you forgot to attatch the image actually. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To 1: Set up a list (aka array) of the field names of the checkboxes. When evaluating, loop through the names and count the number of times the value is `Off`, then subtract this number from the number of checkboxes.

Reason: The field value of an unchecked checkbox field is always `Off`. The value when checked is unknown (because you can chose it).

To 2: I am not quite sure whether I understand what you want to do. But if it is writing the value of field A times a factor into field B, you could do this by adding the following script to the Calculate event of field B:

```
event.value = this.getField("Field A").value x 2 ;
```

And that should do it.